# row numbering based on the number of rows returned by query

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, row-number

I have requirement, where i have to give rownumber for each record returned by my query based on the total count of the rows returned.
lets say a rownumber for each 3 record.
for ex.

```
colA    colB colC(rowno)
1       abc  1
2       asd  1
3       asw  1
4       tre  2
5       cfr  2
6       dfr  2
7       sdf  3
```

I tried with row_number() over (partition by count(*) order by  colA) but it gives the row number as 1 for all the records.

Any idea would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use some maths and the integer division rules:

```
select colA,colB,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY colA)+2)/3 as colC
from table
```

The two integer constants are related - you always want the inner constant (`2`) to be one less than the number of rows which should be assigned the same number (`3`).

Comment: Wow....It works!!...Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever.....I thought i had to write a custom function.....It is awesome!!...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by [Col]) as ColID FROM [TABLE NAME]
WHERE colC = 3
```

Comment: Thanks the response @Nitin..i think my question is still vague....The table shown in my question is returned by my query..The original table doesnt have a colC..

Comment: well, can you post your query?

Comment: this is the query. Select  *,row_number() over (partition by colA,colB order by colA,colB) as colC from TableA  order by colA desc,colB desc